# Does it make sense to have KL divergence between 2 distributions associated with 2 different random variables?

Tags: probability, kullback-leibler

Does it make sense to have KL divergence between 2 PMFs/PDFs/etc associated with two different random variables?

Here is a definition:

"Definition The relative entropy or Kullback-Leibler distance between two probability mass functions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ is defined as
$$
\begin{aligned}
D(p \| q) &=\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} p(x) \log \frac{p(x)}{q(x)} \\
&=E_{p} \log \frac{p(X)}{q(X)}
\end{aligned}
$$"

Comment: That other question is whether " two distribution has same random variable?". Mine is regarding 2 random variables, not 1. I don't think its a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

The mutual information between $X$ and $Y$, $I(X;Y)$, can be seen as the KL-divergence of $P(X,Y)$ and $P(X)P(Y)$. By the way, this is a nice way to show that a mutual information of $0$ implies statistical independence, based on the fact that $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $P(X,Y)=P(X)P(Y)$.

Answer (score 1):

The Kullback-Leibler divergence is a measure of discrepancy between two distributions and thus compares with functional distances ($L_p$, Wasserstein, &tc.). While it can be expressed as an expectation, just like any integral, it does not directly make sense to involve a random variable and even less two random variables. Note however that
$$\mathbb E_{p}\left[ \log\left\{ \frac{p(X)}{q(X)}\right\}\right]
=\mathbb E_{q}\left[ \frac{p(X)}{q(X)}\log \left\{\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}\right\}\right]
=\mathbb E_{p}\left[ \log p(X) \right]-\mathbb E_{q}\left[ \frac{p(X)}{q(X)}\log q(X)\right]$$
could be seen as formally involving two random variables through two expectations.